# Problems with internet connection with bridged connection

Tags: windows, networking, ip

I am having a problem with my network, at the moment it is setup like this:

Wireless Router - Laptop connected to Wifi - Pc connected to laptop via ethernet and bridged connection between WiFi and ethernet.

If I turn both my laptop and PC off and plug in the Ethernet cable, the connection will work fine once everything is on, but if I try and unplug the cable and then plug it back in again, I will get an IP address conflict error and the internet connection wont work on my pc. I then have to restart my pc in order to get it working again.

I have set the IPv4 to automatically select an IP address on both machines but no luck..

Can anyone help me resolve this??

Comment: Try this - unplug the cable (and/or disable PC network adapter), wait about 20 seconds and plug cable back. Is it working again?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.. Tried plugging it in and out a few times aswell. Its almost as if it needs to start up with the cable already in. I'm completely lost here. Could it be my WiFi router??

Comment: It seems complicated. Does it happen when laptop is connected to wifi? Disconnect laptop from wifi and repeat

Comment: Yes it does, I will try that quick. Sorry for late response.

Comment: Sounds like both the PC and the laptop are set to the same local IP address. Not a networking expert so not sure what magic is happening in the Windows bridge on the laptop. Somehow, the PC and the laptop have to have either different IP addresses or Windows is acting like a NAT router to split the traffic using different ports or something.

Comment: But why do you use bridge? It's possible to do it without bridge and without problems. Remove bridge and share WiFi connection with LAN, look [here](http://www.countrymilewifi.com/how-to-share-computers-wifi-with-ethernet-devices.aspx)

Comment: @DocSalvage I think thats exactly whats happening. But I'm going to try what Jet suggested.

Comment: @Jet Thanks, I will try this. Hopefully it works!